# Trying to find name of a short story about astronauts missing the second coming of Jesus on earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration, astronauts

I remember reading about this short story where a group of astronauts are travelling close to the speed of light to a nearby star.

When they return to Earth several years later after completing their mission they find that Jesus returned, gave everyone a few days to set their affairs in order, and then spirited them away to be judged/go to heaven. As the astronauts weren't on Earth when it happened they got left behind and now have to live on an abandoned Earth.

Does anyone know of this story? Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm almost certain you are looking for *Judgement Passed* by Jerry Oltion

Published first in **Wastelands Stories of the Apocalypse**, Edited by John Joseph Adams.

> “Judgment Passed,” which is original to this volume, tells of the Biblical day of judgment from a rationalist viewpoint; a starship crew returns to Earth to find that the rapture has occurred without them. Oltion has strong views on religion–namely that it’s a scourge on humanity–that led him to write this story, which speculates on whether or not being “left behind” would be such a bad thing.

There is an excerpt posted on the same page I got the above blurb from:

http://www.johnjosephadams.com/wastelands/contents/judgment-passed-by-jerry-oltion/

I first heard this story on the Drabblecast Podcast, episode 257

http://www.drabblecast.org/2012/09/23/drabblecast-257-judgement-passed/

Comment: Thank you, that IS the exact story I had stuck in my head. I read that extract years ago. I think I'll also have a read of the Offworld book some others mentioned.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Could this be "[Offworld](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5841844-offworld)" by Robin Parrish? Certainly the main premise (astronauts return to Earth to find the rapture has happened without them) seems to match your description reasonably closely although it's **not a short story** and although they were in space, **they weren't traveling at lightspeed**:

> *The return of NASA's first manned mission to Mars was supposed to be a
>   momentous day. But when the crew loses touch with ground control
>   before entry, things look bleak. Safe after a treacherous landing, the
>   crew emerges to discover the unthinkable--every man, woman, child, and
>   animal has vanished without a trace. Alone now on their home planet,
>   the crew sets out to discover where everyone has gone--and how to get
>   them back--only to discover they may not be as alone as they thought.*