# Deserted earth in the future, child messiah led everyone through hole in ice

Tags: story-identification

(To be clear, I am not a major sci fi reader. Have read the classics by the titans of the genre, but not much more.) 20 years ago a book was recommended and given to me by a friend. I read it and loved it, but lost the book during a move and have forgotten the title and the author. I have asked at numerous bookstores to see if anyone can identify it by the plot. No luck. Any help is appreciated. Here goes:

Earth in the future, a ship from earth crashes and it is several hundred years from when they set out. Earth is deserted. Giant computers ran everything, and have all data about what happened. The astronauts begin to query the computer at a university in the midwest somewhere. The computer tells a story about a child messiah who led everyone through a hole in the Antarctic ice, presumably to a hollow earth (?) but I can't remember exactly.

That was the main arc of the plot. Does this ring any bells ? I would really like to find this book again and re-read it. It was pretty mind blowing. Thanks !

Comment: possibly one of the answers to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89775/trying-to-find-name-of-a-short-story-about-astronauts-missing-the-second-coming ?